# How to use generic classes to solve a Maze?

Tags: java, generics, stack, queue, maze

I am developing a maze-solver program that basically reads a maze from a text file that from the start point, check all sides around it and moves to open spaces, marking the previous position and terminates when the exit is found.

While the algorithm itself is already complete, there are some things I would like to be clarified. The program requires the use of the generic classes Stack, Queue and Coordinates (that stores the current x,y coordinate), which I didn't use (I used Vectors to save the positions) and other operations such as stacking a queue inside the stack.

This is the main loop:

```
if(maz[x][y-1]==' '||maz[x][y-1]=='S'){
    if(maz[x][y-1]=='S')
        exitfound=true;
    maz[x][y]='*';
    maz[x][y-1]='@';
    y=y-1;
}
```

It checks if the coordinate above is either an open space or the exit ('S'), if it's true, it moves there, while marking the previous position with an * and the position it is moving to with an '@'. This repeats with the other 3 sides as well. At the end of the program, all the walked spaces would have been marked with *. However, I need to use said generic classes to manipulate coordinates.

Those are the required classes and its objects:

```
Stack<Coordinate> path = new Stack<Coordinate>(40);
Stack<Queue<Coordinate>> possibilities = new Stack<Queue<Coordinate>>(40);
Coordinate current = new Coordinate(x,y);
Queue<Coordinate> queue = new Queue<Coordinate>(3);
```

I don't understand how to store coordinates on the `current` object and insert coordinates in the `queue` object of the class `Queue<Coordinate>` and stack `queue` object on the `possibilities` object, from the class `Stack<Queue<Coordinate>>`. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to a queue using:

```
queue.add(coordinate);
```

A [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) is like a line at a theme park. The first person in is the first person out (FIFO). A [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) is like a stack of plates. The first plate you put down, is the last one you use. Last-in, First-Out (LIFO).

Javadoc: [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Comment: That was't my question.

Comment: Do you need to know how to add an item to the queue and stack?

Comment: How to add coordinates (ie: 3,4) to the classes Coordinate, stack and queue.

Comment: But a coordinate is not a single integer, how would the queue class store it?